# How to generate random numbers between 0.1 and 0.01

Tags: c, random

I know its possible to generate integer random number using

`(rand() % (difference_between_upper_and_lower_limit)) + lower_limit`

I'm wondering if theres a way to generate a number between 0.1 and 0.01. 
I've tried 
`double speed =  (rand() % 10)/100;`
But it always just gives me 0.0000000;
Thanks in Advance!`

Comment: `/100` is integer division. `/100.0` is floating point division.

Comment: Have you looked at `drand48`? It won't be perfect (i.e., the manipulations you would have to perform upon its result) but it might be adequate for what you need. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058848/generate-a-random-double-between-1-and-1) for some ideas.

Comment: There are an infinite amount of numbers between 0.1 and 0.01. Do you mean that you want to generate a random number from the ten numbers in this set (0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10)? If not what do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455271/integer-division-always-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an uniform distribution on an arbitrary interval with

```
((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*(i_end-i_start)+i_start
```

where `i_start` and `i_end` denote the start and end of the interval.

In your case try

```
((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)*0.09+0.01
```

Comment: Let us call this uniform-ish.  OK for basic programs.

Comment: @chux Yes, it gives at maximum `RAND_MAX+1` different results, which is most likely less then doubles in that interval. There are probably better functions to use, like `drand48()`, but i wanted to stick with the random function he mentioned in his question.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you missed the type-casting part ==> *(**(double)**(rand() % 10))/100;*

Try this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
  // If you don't set the seed-value, you'll always get the same random numbers returned in every execution of the code
  srand(time(0));

  double speed = ((double)(rand() % 10))/100;
  printf("%f\n", speed );

  speed = ((double)(rand() % 10))/100;
  printf("%f\n", speed );

  speed = ((double)(rand() % 10))/100;
  printf("%f\n", speed );

  speed = ((double)(rand() % 10))/100;
  printf("%f\n", speed );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use `float` when [0.01...0.1] (`double` constants) was specified and OP used `double speed`?

Comment: My mistake.... I thought OP has 'float'.
Updated my answer.

Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Note this will generate values [0 to 0.09] rather than [0.01 to 0.1].  `speed = (rand() % 10)/100.0;` would be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
double upper_limit = .1;
double lower_limit = .01;
double value = ((upper_limit-lower_limit)*rand())/RAND_MAX + lower_limit;
```