# Detect IEEE-754 floating point representation at compile time

Tags: c, ieee-754, compile-time

I'm looking for a way to detect whether a C compiler uses the IEEE-754 floating point representation at compile time, preferably in the preprocessor, but a constant expression is fine too.

Note that the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro does not fit this purpose, as an implementation may use the correct representation while not fully supporting Annex F.

Comment: Most likely the compiler itself will be "using" whatever format used by the underlying hardware.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think he means "implementation", which is the combination of hardware, compiler, libraries, etc.

Comment: A common issue with `__STDC_IEC_559__` is its "shall implement floating point types (what OP wants - easy enough to comply) and arithmetic conforming to IEC 60559 (the hard part)".  The "arithmetic conforming to IEC 60559" is a hard test to do, let alone pass.  Some highly compliant compilers leave it undefined rather than risk a missed corner case.

Answer (score 3):

Not an absolute 100% solution, but will get you practically close.

Check if the characteristics of floating type `double` match [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

```
#include <float.h>

#define BINARY64_LIKE ( \
  (FLT_RADIX == 2) \
  (DBL_MANT_DIG == 53)  \
  (DBL_DECIMAL_DIG == 17) \
  (DBL_DIG == 15) \
  (DBL_MIN_EXP == -1021) \
  (DBL_HAS_SUBNORM == 1) \
  (DBL_MIN_10_EXP == -307) \
  (DBL_MAX_EXP == +1024) \
  (DBL_MAX_10_EXP == +308))
```

`BINARY64_LIKE` usable at compile time.  Need additional work though for older compilers that do not define them all like: `DBL_HAS_SUBNORM` since C11.

Likewise for `float`.

Since C11, code could use `_Static_assert()` to detect some attributes.

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(double)*CHAR_BIT == 64, "double unexpected size");
```

See also [Are there any commonly used floating point formats besides IEEE754?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51008244/2410359).

Last non-IEEE754 FP format I used was [CCSI](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format) 5 years ago.

---

Caution: Unclear *why* OP wants this test.  If code is doing some bit manipulations of a floating point, even with `__STDC_IEC_559__` defined there remains at least one hole: The endian of floating point and integer may differ - uncommon - but out there.

Other potential holes: support of -0.0, NaN sign, encoding of infinity, signalling NaN, quiet NaN, NaN payload: the usual suspects.

Comment: A [link to page with the floating point MACRO reference for C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits#Limits_of_floating_point_types).

Comment: @Myst Thanks for the link.   Pretty much one can use all characteristics except ones like `DBL_MAX, FLT_MIN` as those do not work uniformly well with preprocessor math.

Comment: There is no need to check the values with `DECIMAL` or `10` in their names, because they are functions of the others, which completely characterize the representable values except for infinity and NaN support. (Hypothetically, a format could use more bits and allow, say, unnormalized representations. But the set if representable values would be the same.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil  A reasonable simplification.

Comment: "The endian of floating point and integer may differ" - I was unaware of this issue, thanks for mentioning it. Is there any straightforward way to detect this?

Comment: @vktec I think `_Static_assert()` and some `union` magic test can work.  But endian FP/integer same-ness is stepping beyond "Detect IEEE-754 floating point representation at compile time" as IEEE does not spec FP nor integer endian.  If your real goal is beyond that, perhaps post that question.

Comment: Most machines not using IEEE754 are in museums or junkyards.  That standard is 1/3 century old and has been heavily adopted.  Granted, the "usual suspects" held out for a long time.

Comment: By most "weight" I agree and older big-iron machines with variant FP encodings are are now historic curiosities.  But by "most", I am not so sure.  There are billions of embedded processors made each year and for the past 20-5 years ago, millions, if not 10s millions of those used variant FP owing to the need for simple FP and no HW FP support.  IAC, I suspect OP's final goal remains hidden as the need for "Detect IEEE-754 floating point representation at compile time" makes sense to reduce/simplify  regression testing, yet I suspect OP is doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2020, this would still be compiler specific... though [C2x intends to change that with the `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` macro](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2478.pdf) - see Annex F, section F.2.

It might be noted that:

- The compiler **usually** doesn't choose the binary representation. The compiler usually follows the target system's architecture (the chipset instruction design for the CPU / GPU, etc').
- The use of non-conforming binary representations for floating-point is pretty much a thing of the past. If you're using a modern (or even a moderately modern) system from the past 10 years, you are **almost** certainly using a conforming binary representation.

Comment: @KamilCuk ,yes, you're right. I usually paint in broad strokes and missed the details on that one. I updated the answer, I hope it's better now.

Comment: It seems to me that `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__` still requires conformant arithmetic. Am I misreading the draft standard?

Comment: @vktec  the macro also requires the `float` and `double` types to use specific IEEE 754 binary representations (though using the updated specification documents and names). This was the root of your question, right?

Comment: Then it has the same issue as `__STDC_IEC_559__`: an implementation that uses the desired *representation* in memory may not implement all operations correctly and may thus not define the macro